# Ride with Uber button opens up appstore instead of Uber App

Tags: ios, uber-api

I know how to correctly implement a "RideRequestButton". But when I try to implement the same in my Project, and when I tap on the "Ride With Uber" button, it opens up the App Store. Can anyone help?

Comment: what URL scheme are you using?

Comment: Can you please share with us how did you implemented "RideRequestButton"? Some code samples can help us to see did you configured and implemented this properly.

Comment: I actually figured out, what the problem is....Hoping you guys have a solution to this...My app uses Facebook for login...According to FB docs step number 4.3 needs to be inserted into you info.plist. Heres the link...https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios

FB mentions "If you use any of the Facebook dialogs (e.g., Login, Share, App Invites, etc.) that can perform an app switch to Facebook apps, your application's .plist also need to handle this."

How do you fix this? I need both FB login and Uber ride request button in my app.

Comment: @holex I am not sure, what u mean by URL scheme...Could you please explain? Maybe take a look at my code...and please read the above comment : https://github.com/iamchingel/Chingel

Comment: Sanket, can you please confirm (1) that you have the Uber app installed, (2) what version of the iOS SDK you have, and (3) that you have the uber and the uberauth schemes added to your info.plist? https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk#sdk-configuration

Comment: @EdwardJiang I figured it out..all i had to do was add "uber" to LSApplicationQueriesScheme

Comment: @SasaJovanovic Thank you ..i figured it out